# VBA - Scrolling Google Reviews

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I would like to open a Google search using VBA; IE. Once open I would like to click "Google reviews" link to open the "Google Reviews" top-level page. Once open I would like to scroll only the "Google Reviews" top-level page. I only need to scroll once.

As you can see in my code snippet, it will do everything I wish but not give focus to the top-level page. When I scroll, it scrolls the background. This opens an IE Google search for Anchor Bar, Buffalo NY. Clicks the link for Reviews. Then scrolls the background.

My question is how can I scroll the "Google Reviews" page, not the background with the search results.

```
Public Sub main()

 On Error Resume Next

 Dim IE As Object
 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 IE.Navigate "https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=VN-FWqLyEongzgLHx574Cw&q=anchor+bar+buffalo&oq=anchor+bar+&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0l10.1937.3478.0.5460.11.10.0.1.1.0.152.810.7j2.9.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.10.819...0i131k1j0i131i46k1j46i131k1.0.49jjww0NNUE"
 IE.Visible = True

 waitFor 6
 Debug.Print "Bring up Reviews"
 IE.document.querySelector("span.fl > span > a > span ").Click
 waitFor 6


 Debug.Print "Scroll Child Window Here"

 IE.document.parentwindow.Scroll 0, 99999

 waitFor 2

 Set Reviews = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("_ucl")
 For Each r In Reviews
     Debug.Print "review: " & r.innerHTML
 Next

 Debug.Print "The End"

End Sub

Sub waitFor(i As Long)
   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:0" & i))
End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing `IE.document.parentWindow.Scroll` to `IE.document.parentWindow.ScrollBy`

Comment: .ScrollBy appears to do the same thing as .Scroll

Comment: To scroll the reviews: `document.querySelector(".review-dialog-list").scrollTop = 99999`

Comment: @FlorentB. Great use of querySelector!! This certainly answers my question. I am unable to recognize you since I am a new user.